# Unable to save to DB, string was not recognized as a valid DateTime MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two text boxes that are enabled based on a checkbox. If `checked == true` then enable editing. Until this point everything is fine. However, when I hit the **Submit** button to save it to the database, it's not working. I was able to save it with just one of the text boxes being editable. Now that I have two editable boxes, it's not working.

**Problem:**

The ajax call is sending the dates and the ID back to the controller method. However, it's not getting saved to the DB. In **UpdatePlannedDate** I put in a couple breakpoints, its completely skipping over the first **forEach loop**.

**The Exception it's throwing:**
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

**Model Class:**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Date1{ get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Date2{ get; set; }

public string R_ID { get; set; }
public string U_ID { get; set; }
public string C_ID { get; set; }
```

**Controller class:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdatePlannedDate(string ids, string Date1, string Date2)
    {
        model = new Hello();
        Entity db = new Entity();
        List<Hello> list = new List<Hello>();
        string[] IDS = ids.Split(',');
        string[] Date1S = Date1.Split(',');
        string[] Date2S = Date2.Split(',');

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < IDS.Length; i++)
            {
                if (IDS[i] != null && IDS[i] != "")
                {
                    Hello item = new Hello { R_ID = IDS[i], Date_Two = DateTime.Parse(Date2S[i]), Date_One = DateTime.Parse(Date1S[i]) };
                    list.Add(item);
                }
            }
            foreach (var row in db.table1)  
            {
                foreach (var row2 in db.table2) 
                {
                    if (row.U_ID == row2.C_ID)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in list)
                        {
                            if (row.U_ID == item.R_ID)
                            {
                                var cd = db.Table2.Where(x => x.C_ID == row.U_ID).First();
                                cd.PlanDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date_Two);
                                cd.PlanDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date_One);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true, msg = "Updated" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, msg = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

**View class:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var ids = "";
        var date1 = "";
        var date2 = "";

        //Save to DB
        $("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function () {
            createUpdateArrays();
            var url = "/Sample/UpdatePlannedDate";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: { ids: ids, date1: date1, date2: date2 },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $('.msg').html('Updated');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                }
            });

            ids = "";
            date1 = "";
            date2 = "";
        });
        function createUpdateArrays() {
            var i = 0;
            $('input.remedy-id:checkbox').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    var rid = $(this).attr("id");
                    $('.date2').each(function () {
                        var did = $(this).attr("id");
                        if (did === rid) {
                            var date_2 = $(this).val();
                            ids += rid + ",";
                            date2 += date_2 + ",";
                        }
                    });
                    $('.date1').each(function () {
                        var tid = $(this).attr("id");
                        if (tid === rid) {
                            var date_1 = $(this).val();
                            ids += rid + ",";
                            date1 += date_1 + ",";
                        }
                    });
                };
            });
        };

    <tr id="home">
        <td><input class="id" type="checkbox" id=@item.R_ID/></td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.R_ID)</td>
        <td><input class="date1" id=@item.R_ID type="text" value='@(item.Date1 == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date1).ToString("MM/dd/yyy"))' readonly="readonly" /></td>
        <td><input class="date2" id=@item.R_ID type="text" value='@(item.Date2 == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date2).ToString("MM/dd/yyy"))' readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the id? I am not entirely sure how this is being generated. `id=@item.R_ID`

Comment: @Jacob its all coming from a database and its in the same format as the dates I have defined in the model class.

Comment: What specifically was added that was different from the code that working before with ONE input field?

Answer (score 0):

1) What is your ORM? Entity Framework?

2) Try to debug line:

```
 Hello item = new Hello { R_ID = IDS[i], Date_Two = DateTime.Parse(Date2S[i]), Date_One = DateTime.Parse(Date1S[i]) };
```

3) Isn't datetime conversion twice there?
First Hello item = ... line, second there

```
                            cd.PlanDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date_Two);
                            cd.PlanDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date_One);
```

4) What will do the change:

```
cd.PlanDate = item.Date_Two;
cd.PlanDate = item.Date_One;
```

?

5) Isn't also a logical fault there to have assignation of 2 values to one variable here?

6) Do you have any javascript extension to your fields on side of Razor template? What format it will produce here if you will pick your time from calendar? Does it fits to your definition mask in model class? (

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

)

Comment: I had to add a client side date format validation, those were not the problems